# Chequear elementos dentro de array bidimensional?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
var x = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

y debo chequear que los elementos del array esten exactamente en ese orden. Hice la siguiente funcion:

```
function chequearSiGano() {
  for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    if (x[0]=[1,2,3]){
      return true;
    }
    else if (x[1]=[4,5,6]){
      return true;
    }
    else if (x[2]=[7,8,9]){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

pero queria saber si hay alguna manera mas eficiente de hacerlo para poder aplicarla en el caso de que se agreguen en un futuro elemento al array. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te agrego esta otra respuesta en base a la sucesión que comienza desde **1**:

*esto aplica para varios vectores como* :

```
x = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]];

x = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,10,11,12]];

x = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6],
     [7,8,9,10,11,12]];
```

O lo que se te ocurra (siempre que **x[0][0]=1** *tal como lo muestra tu ejemplo* )

La idea esta en verificar cada posición si es mayor por 1 a la posición anterior:

```
function chequearSiGano(){
    bandera = true;
    valor = 0;
    x.forEach((i)=>{
        i.forEach((j)=>{
            if(j === valor+1) valor++; // aquí es donde se verifica la sucesión con la posición anterior
            else bandera = false;
        });
    });
    return bandera;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Toma en cuenta que si tu primera condición cumple entonces no entrará a los demás casos, y eso no quiere decir que este exactamente en ese orden como lo pides. Así que la lógica estaría mal planteada. Además nunca usas la variable que itera en el bucle *for*

Para poder verificarlo podrías hacerlo de esta manera usando *&&*:

```
function chequearSiGano() {
    if ( (x[0]=[1,2,3]) && (x[1]=[4,5,6]) && (x[2]=[7,8,9])) {
      return true;
    }

    else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

O la forma más simple de todas, comparar la variable con la matriz:

```
function chequearSiGano() {
        if ( x === [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]] ) {
          return true;
        }

        else {
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: pero si el dia de ma;ana quisiera agregar elementos a la matriz esto ya no me serviria, de que manera puedo hacerlo global?

Comment: entonces tal vez falte alguna aclaración tuya a la pregunta.... cual seria el orden??? de menor a mayor? sucesivo?...  También aclarar que si fuera de esa forma entonces todo dependería del primer elemento del array

Comment: tenes que tener en cuenta que sea cualquiera de esas dos opciones(de menor a mayor o sucesivo) de todas formas el código tiene que automatizar la verificación... Por favor aclara a que te refieres con *exactamente en ese orden*

Comment: me refiero a si mañana la matriz tiene 12 elementos en vez de 9. Seria de menor a mayor.

Comment: Seria de recorrer la matriz de 1 a n.

Comment: Ya te puse otra respuesta siguiendo eso mismo, espero te haya servido. Suerte..

Comment: Gracias! se podria tb hacer con un for anidado?

Comment: También se puede, pero al usar *for()* también tienes que controlar el tamaño de tus vectores... El foreach está hecho precisamente para ejecutar una instrucción por cada elemento del array... Como lo es en tu caso(evaluar si son sucesivos)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Si tu matriz siempre va a tener 3 columnas y n filas, puedes recorrer primero las filas y ver si cada valor del vector **x[i]** corresponde con el valor que deberia tener segun la fila x 3 y la columna + 1:

```js
var x = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 7, 9]
];

function chequearSiGano() {
  for (var i in x)
    for(var j in x[i])
      if (x[i][j]!=+j+1+3*i)
        return false;
  return true;
}

console.log(chequearSiGano());

var x = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12]
];

console.log(chequearSiGano());
```

La primera matriz esta incorrecta y la segunda correcta.